# Vim: sort using multiple patterns

Tags: regex, sorting, vim

I know that, in vim, I can sort a file using a regular expression to indicate which parts of each row I want to use to consider while sorting using:

```
:sort 'regex' r
```

Is it possible to combine more than one expression?

Here you have an example:

INPUT:

```
bar a 2
foo b 1
bar b 1
foo a 2
```

:sort '[a-z]' r

```
foo b 1
bar b 1
bar a 2
foo a 2
```

sort '[0-9]' r

```
bar a 2
bar b 1
foo b 1
foo a 2
```

EXPECTED (maybe something "like" :sort '[A-Z]|[0-9]' r ?):

```
bar b 1
bar a 2
foo b 1
foo a 2
```

Please note that a bare "sort" does not work, due to those "a" and "b" which break the digits order

```
bar a 2
bar b 1
foo a 2
foo b 1
```

An alternative outside VIM is also accepted, but, for sake of curiosity, I would like to know if it's actually possible to do it within VIM (and if afermative, how ;-)

Many thanks,
Regards

Comment: The result of `sort '[0-9]' r` is not pasted correctly. The result should be different.

Comment: @Birei: You're right. Just corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Confused. Is the first block the values inputted? The second seems to be for `sort '[0-9]' r` (assuming the first represents the initial state) and not `sort '[a-z]' r`, and the third for `sort '[a-z]' r` (again assuming the first is the initial state, and we didn't run another sort first), not `sort '[0-9]' r. I think. Perhaps you edited the second when you meant to edit the third after Birei's comment? And EXPECTED is give or take INTENDED or DESIRED?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you have external sort available, the following should work:

```
:%!sort -k1,1 -k3,3n
```

EDIT: Explanation:

`-k` is used to specify sort keys.  `-k1,1` implies start sort on `key1` and end it `key1`.  `-k3,3n` implies start sort on `key3` and end it `key3`; `n` here denotes numeric sort, i.e. compare according to string numerical value.

By default, sort assumes blank to non-blank transition as the field separator.  As such, it'd consider the line `bar b 1` to comprise of three fields.  If the values were delimited by a specific character other than space, say `:`, you would specify the field-separator by adding `-t:`.

Comment: Right, that works! However, would you mind explaining the meaning of the params, so I can easily extend it to different (real, this was a simplified example) situations?

Comment: @CarlesSala see explanation above.

Comment: Isn't this just a [command line call from within VIm sending `%` as the range to operate on](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/321/3342)? Though obviously that works for the OP, it's less useful for Windows [outside of Powershell], and isn't _really_ a VIm answer, right? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

There is a flaw in what you are asking for... If you want to sort by the first word AND the number, then you need to somehow specify the order of precedence. In other words, do you want the sorted list to look like this:

```
bar b 1
bar a 2
foo b 1
foo a 2
```

or, this:

```
bar b 1
foo b 1
bar a 2
foo a 2
```

Obviously, the answer is the first one. But you need to tell vim that! Hence, I can't think of any (sensible) way to do that in one command...
But, I can do it in two:

```
:sort /\d/ r
:sort /[a-z]/ r
```

By doing the commands *in this order*, you are specifying that the first word takes priority over the number.

Comment: I don't see the flaw...The need of an order for such a request is obvious, and although I didn't specify the order explicitly I did it implicitly (I said want to use two rules, suggested '[a-z]|[0-9]', pasted the result...).
Anyway, would you mind explaing why your suggestion works? What are these /\d/ and /[a-z]/ actually doing?

Comment: \d is equivalent to [0-9].

/.../ is equivalent to typing '...', in this context.

My syntax is probably the more "standardised" way of doing this, but there's nothing wrong with yours. It means the same thing. You can also just type :sor, instead of :sort, if you want to save that extra keystroke - but I didn't bother confusing you with that!

The flaw is that the :sort command looks for **a** pattern in the each line, then reorders the rows based on that pattern. You are looking for two different patterns, which is outside the scope of the command (I think. As far as I can tell.)

Comment: But also, the point is, how are you going to tell vim to sort column 1 over column 3, and ignore column 2? I'm pretty sure that's not even possible... and why bother, when you can just do it in 2 simple commands anyway?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanations Tom. I didn't think about doing it in two steps, but it's difinitely an option. However, I took devnull's answer as the valid one because it is exportable to outside of vim (for example, piping it after another command).